# Including User First Name & Last Name on Auth0 Sign Up

Tags: auth0

I'm using auth0.js (v8) to sign a user up using the following method:

`webAuth.signup({connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication', email, password}, callback);`

How may I also set the user's first name/last name?

Answer (score 0):

You can send extra metadata as part of `user_metadata` option for `signup` method http://auth0.github.io/auth0.js/docs/global.html#signup

```
webAuth.signup({connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication'
    , email : useremail, password : userpwd
    , user_metadata : " 'First Name' : 'Tony'
       , 'Last Name' : 'Stark'"
  }, callback);
```

For reference https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/custom-signup#custom-fields-limitations and the underlying api docs are [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#signup)